# Vuejs: How can I pass vue js prop value to attribute of html as a value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, countdowntimer

I want to show a counter on remaining time in vuejs. I am using flip-countdown library of vue. I want to pass remaining_time prop value to attribute of html code.

Html:

```
<flip-countdown deadline=remaining_time></flip-countdown>
```

Script:

```
<script>
import FlipCountdown from 'vue2-flip-countdown'
    export default {
        components: { FlipCountdown },
        props: ['id'],

        data(){
            return {
                 items:{},

                 remaining_time:"2019-12-25 00:00:00",


            }
        },
</script>
```

I want to pass this remaining_time above to the html attribute as value but this code is not working. Please guide how to pass remaining_time value to above attribute deadline in html.

Comment: Use :deadline="remaining_time"

Comment: Just making sure; there's a typo with your brackets, seeing that the provided answers didn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right,

```
<flip-countdown :deadline="remaining_time"></flip-countdown>
```

is correct answer.

Please be sure your are using right **format for date-time** `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Here is an example 
https://github.com/philipjkim/vue2-flip-countdown/blob/master/demo/src/App.vue

Comment: Thanks bro it works when I pass seconds in this  deadline1: now.add(10, 's').format(fmt). How can I pass complete deadline date?

Answer (score 3):

You must bind it to the attribute:

```
<flip-countdown v-bind:deadline="remaining_time"></flip-countdown>
```

or simply:

```
<flip-countdown :deadline="remaining_time"></flip-countdown>
```